# Where can I buy European-style options?

Tags: options, broker

My broker (Ameritrade) makes several options available in their platform (thinkorswim). It seems like these are mostly American options (can be exercised at any time). There does not seem to be any possibility of electing to buy European options.

Where does one buy European options?

Answer (score 3):

On the US markets, most index options are European style.  Most stock and ETF options are, as you noted, American style.